# Deliberately setting an invalid css property

Tags: css, user-interface, sass, less

I would like to deliberately set an scss variable with a string as a property value which will be read as invalid and therefore will have no effect on my ui. E.g.

```
$invalid: "thiswontwork";
.my-element { background: $invalid; }
```

This value will just be considered as invalid and ignored.
I know that my variable would throw an error if it were used in a function like "lighten()".
Is there any other scenario where adding a string like "thiswontwork" as my property value could cause an issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple scenarios. For example, I would like to mention three:

- `color`
- `content`
- `display`

As with `background`, the same error comes for `color`.

With respect to `content`, there won't be any error with CSS syntax but you can visibly see it's messed up.

With display, the set of enumerated values is what you need to use. Here it might throw an error, invalid value for `display`.